# How do I make the entire nav bar fixed instead of just the buttons?

Tags: html, css

If the nav bar isn't fixed, 
[the entire thing is visible including the extra non-link space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWnq2.png)

code:

```
div class="sec1">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="mikaproj.html"  class="project"> TEXT</a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jewishtea/" target="_blank" 
class="button"> TEXT</a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/aliacatil" target="_blank" 
class="button"> TEXT</a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEEvH5lJzkCf7rb10CQAnyg" ta 
   rget="_blank" class="button"> TEXT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.topnav {
    background-color: #f7b733;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: relative;


}


.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Osaka, serif;
 }


.topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #fc4a1a;
   color: white;
}
```

but when it IS fixed, [The extra yellow space disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfNSP.png)

help?

Answer (score 0):

When you use position fixed you should determine top, left and right. Try these codes:

```
.is-fixed
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read This [css positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```css
.topnav {
    background-color: #f7b733;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;


}


.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Osaka, serif;
 }


.topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #fc4a1a;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="sec1">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="mikaproj.html"  class="project"> TEXT</a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jewishtea/" target="_blank" 
class="button"> TEXT</a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/aliacatil" target="_blank" 
class="button"> TEXT</a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEEvH5lJzkCf7rb10CQAnyg" ta 
   rget="_blank" class="button"> TEXT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```